# React-select: custom Control does not render select components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui, react-select

Working with `react-select@next` and following the example [here](https://deploy-preview-2289--react-select.netlify.com/components#replaceable-components) for custom `Control` components does not give the expected result.

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Select from "react-select";

const InputComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <TextField {...props} />
    );
};

export const MaterialSelect = (props) => {
    const { suggestions, ...other } = props;
    return (
            <Select
                options={suggestions}
                components={{
                    Control: InputComponent,
                }}
                {...other}
            />
    );
};

const suggestions = [
    {
        label: "Test One",
        value: "testOne",
    },
    {
        label: "Test Two",
        value: "testTwo",
    },
];

<MaterialSelect suggestions={suggestions} />
```

Using the Material-UI TextField does not open the dropdown or display any of the adornments. I also tried passing in `{...props.selectProps}` instead of `{...props}` to the `TextField` with no luck

I also tried passing the components in individually using the `InputProps` prop for `TextField` with no luck. Using `menuIsOpen` on my `Select` component renders the menu as expected, however typing in to the `TextField` produces no results, no adornments, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are struggling to make react select looks like material.
assuming that I can give you an example:

first you need to implement your Options looks like material:

```
class Option extends React.Component {
  handleClick = event => {
    this.props.selectOption(this.props.data, event);
  };

  render() {
    const { children, isFocused, isSelected, onFocus } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <MenuItem
        onFocus={onFocus}
        selected={isFocused}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        component="div"
        style={{
          fontWeight: isSelected ? 500 : 400
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </MenuItem>
    );
  }
}
```

then you need to wrap react-select and put is as a **inputComponent** prop in material-ui Input.

```
function SelectWrapped(props) {
  const { classes, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Select
      components={{
        Option: Option,
        DropdownIndicator: ArrowDropDownIcon
      }}
      styles={customStyles}
      isClearable={true}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}
```

then use it as:

```
 <div className={classes.root}>
    <Input
      fullWidth
      inputComponent={SelectWrapped}
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      placeholder="Search your values"
      id="react-select-single"
      inputProps={{
        options: testOptions
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

please fins that I have passes the options as inputProps in the example.

here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nk2mkvx92p

please find these **customStyles** in the demo which make more material feel in your component.

hope this will you.

Comment: thank you @gluttony! I realized soon after this that there was no way to use the `TextField` component as my `Control` in `Select`. I was hoping to avoid using the `Input` component because `TextField` comes with some more functionality but it's ok. This is exactly what I ended up with as well :)